# Solr search return in JSON format returned values wrapped in array

Tags: solr

I cannot figure out why my search result always return the values wrapped in array -- I index as a normal key-value document and yet the values seems to be in array.

Am I missing something when I index the data or something to do with my query format?

`{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"ember",
      "indent":"on",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"20",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1460536046068"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "content":["A little while back, I wrote a blog post introducing ember-suave,\n an addon that we created at DockYard to help enforce a common code \nstyle across all of our projects. With the addon installed, any code \nthat doesn't align with the established styleguide will cause the build \nto fail. During development, as files are modified, the linter will \nreprocess the changed files, displaying errors in the console right \naway.https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/02/29/code-linting-inside-look"],
        "createdAt":["2016-04-13T08:19:24.321Z"],
        "updatedAt":["2016-04-13T08:19:24.823Z"],
        "id":"7102mmzmya4e",
        "type":["post"],
        "_version_":1531482543265677312}]
  }}`

Comment: Please post your schema.xml here.

Comment: check you schema.xml if all the fields are having multivalues as true?

Comment: multiValued=true|false...
True if this field may contain multiple values per document, i.e. if it can appear multiple times in a document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have mentioned `multiValued` attribute defined in the schema whether the field is allowed to have more than one value.

For instance:
if you have a fieldType which is multiValued=true,

`True` if this field may contain multiple values per document, i.e. if it can appear multiple times in a document

You must have added it as `multiValued=true`, so it will consider the field has multiple values to it...so returning it as an array..

Comment: You are right. Multivalued must have been the defaults of the schema I use.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **schemaless** setup, all the automatically created fields will be multiValued, with that flag defined on the type itself. That's because the algorithm does not know whether a single value will always stay a single value or become a multiValue later.

You can change the algorithm (mapping) in solrconfig.xml or you can add multiValued="false" in the **managed-schema**, reload, and reindex.